# Unknown way of reading int with masking

Tags: java, android, c, image-processing

I try to work around the various limitations of *Android*, but I am quite puzzled how to interpret the following code

```
static bool read_mbf(SkStream* stream, int* value)
{
    int n = 0;
    uint8_t data;
    do {
        if (!read_byte(stream, &data)) {
            return false;
        }
        n = (n << 7) | (data & 0x7F); // Appends lower 7 bits
    } while (data & 0x80); // Handles upper bit as flag!?

    *value = n;
    return true;
}
```

It seems to me like the upper bit is a flag for *data continues*. And when it is missing, reading int stops. Is this correct?

To correctly encode this in Java (also see Daniel's Answer):

```
private void encode( byte[] array, int offset, int value ) {
    if( (value & 0xF0000000) != 0 )
        throw new InvalidParameterException("Value " + value + "is too big to be encoded (max: " + 0x0FFFFFFF + ")");

    // | 0x80 makes sure, upper most bit is set so next byte is processed
    // & 0x7F makes sure, upper most bit is NOT set to end processing
    array[offset + 0] = (byte)((value >> 21) | 0x80);
    array[offset + 1] = (byte)((value >> 14) | 0x80);
    array[offset + 2] = (byte)((value >>  7) | 0x80);
    array[offset + 3] = (byte)((value >>  0) & 0x7F);
}
```

Could someone confirm or point out what I did wrong?

EDIT:

Updated Java code to reflect corrections by Daniel Fischer

Comment: Your interpretation of the C code sounds sensible. In Java you have to beware because all integral types are signed.

Comment: That wouldn't work. The c function is reading ints that were encoded into the least possible number of bytes to save space. E.g. 0 to 127 take one byte. You are always putting out four bytes no matter what. The c function would expect one byte in that case, and read the following into other numbers when called again.

Comment: @DiegoBasch I don't really get what you are saying. If you have `10000000`, the seven `0` would be shifted to left and simply have no effect. Sure, I could clamp the unnecessary empty bytes, but IMO it should work.

Comment: The c function is called repeatedly to read numbers from a stream of bytes. If you encode 127 into four bytes, it would consume only one of those four. The next time it will read the second of your four bytes thinking it's a new number.

Comment: I would expect this to work since the `0x80` (_continue_) bit is set. But perhaps I am too tired. Will have a look again tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is almost correct, but due to being too tired, you shift the wrong value in the wrong direction:

```
array[offset + 0] = (byte)((value & (0x7F << 21)) | 0x80);
```

So you mask out all bits except those in positions 21 to 27 from `value`, and then bitwise-or it with `0x80`. Then you cast the result to `byte`, which means discard all but the least significant 8 bits. That leaves

```
array[offset + 0] = (byte)0x80;
```

You want

```
array[offset + 0] = (byte)(((value >> 21) & 0x7F) | 0x80);
```

etc.

And your condition for the exception,

```
if( (value & 0xF0000000) == 0xF0000000 )
```

isn't correct. That throws only if all four most significant bits are set. If only some of them are set, your encoding just discards them. The condition could be

```
if( (value & 0xF0000000) != 0 )
```

to check whether any of these bits is set.

But do you really want that exception? There is no reason in the C code for that limitation (there is, however, a reason to disallow negative `int`s, since those would lead to overflow and hence undefined behaviour when left-shifting the last time).

If you want to encode any non-negative `int` with the smallest number of bytes that encoding allows, the code becomes a bit more complicated, since the number of bytes used varies with the magnitude of the encoded value.

```
private int encode( byte[] array, int offset, int value ) {
    if (value < 0)
        throw new InvalidParameterException("Value " + value + " is negative and cannot safely be decoded.");
    byte temp;
    int shift = 28;
    // find highest set septet
    while(shift > 0 && (value >> shift) == 0) {
        shift -= 7;
    }
    // encode parts that have a successor
    while(shift > 0) {
        array[offset++] = (byte)(((value >> shift) & 0x7F) | 0x80);
        shift -= 7;
    }
    // last septet
    array[offset++] = (byte)(value & 0x7F);
    // return offset for next value
    return offset;
}
```

The line

```
array[offset++] = (byte)(((value >> shift) & 0x7F) | 0x80);
```

could also be written

```
array[offset++] = (byte)((value >> shift) | 0x80);
```

since the cast to `byte` discards all other bits.

(I have omitted checks for `offset < array.length`, since that's not part of the algorithm, they should be added for safety.)

Comment: Great. Thx. Incorporated changes into my question. IMO my naive approach is a little easier to read/understand.

Comment: Oh, definitely. A fixed-length encoding gives easier code. But it can take more space, see UTF-n.